# How inject Memcached class to service Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, service, memcached, containers

I want ot inject Memcached class into my servcie by setter injection. But I dont know how I can do this. Can somebody help me?
Here what I already tried:

```
<service id="uber.memcached" class="Bundle" >
        <call method="setMemcached">
            \Memcached
        </call>
    </service>
```

Comment: Create a new service with class `Memcached` then inject it to your service. E.g: `<service id="memcached" class="Memcached" /><service id="uber.memcached" class="Bundle"><call method="setMemcached"><argument type="service" id="memcached" /></call></service>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your services into service.xml file

```
// memcached service
<service id="memcached" class="Memcached" />

// memcached injection 
<service id="uber.memcached" class="App\Bundle\Foo">
  <call method="setMemcached">
    <argument type="service" id="memcached" />
  </call>
</service>
```

And then, use it on your service class

```
// App/Bundle/Foo.php

namespace App\Bundle;

Class Foo {

   public function setMemcached($service) { 
      // your code
   }
}
```